# Flattening 1 level of object array and appending parent object

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have an object like which I want to flatten:

```
const obj = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'parent1',
      children: [ 
          {
            childName: ''child11"
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'parent2',
      children: [ 
          {
            childName: ''child21"
          },
          {
            childName: ''child22"
          }
      ]
    }
]
```

I want my object to be like below:

```
eObj = [
    {
        p_id: 1,
        p_name: "parent1",
        childName: "child11"
    },
    {
        p_id: 2,
        p_name: "parent2",
        childName: "child21"
    },
    {
        p_id: 2,
        p_name: "parent2",
        childName: "child22"
    }
]
```

I have done it using:

```
      const eObj = [];
      obj.forEach((o) => {
        o.children.forEach((co) => {
          eObj.push({
            p_id: o.id,
            p_name: o.name,
            ...children,
          });
        });
      });
```

Is there a better way to do it, and also to reduce the nested for loop? I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Your input array is invalid. Check those quotes.

Comment: If your current implementation works, a better place for this question would probably be: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in what solution is more efficient.
Turns out your double `forEach`-solution is actually faster than the `flatMap` & `map`.

**`flatMap` & `map`**

```js
const obj = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "parent1",
    children: [{
      childName: "child11",
    }, ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "parent2",
    children: [{
        childName: "child21",
      },
      {
        childName: "child22",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = obj.flatMap(({
    children,
    id,
    name
  }) =>
  children.map((child) => ({
    p_id: id,
    p_name: name,
    childName: child.childName,
  }))
);

console.log(result);
```

**double `forEach`**

```js
const obj = [{
    id: 1,
    name: "parent1",
    children: [{
      childName: "child11",
    }, ],
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "parent2",
    children: [{
        childName: "child21",
      },
      {
        childName: "child22",
      },
    ],
  },
];

const result = [];
obj.forEach((o) => {
  o.children.forEach((co) => {
    result.push({
      p_id: o.id,
      p_name: o.name,
      childName: co.childName,
    });
  });
});

console.log(result);
```

[image: JSBench.me comparison]

Answer (score 0):

You can use flatmap. This works:

```
eObj = obj.flatMap(item => item.children.map(child => ({p_id: item.id, p_name: item.name, childName: child.childName})))
```

Answer (score 0):

Each way to do that needs two levels loop. You may use `map` or `reduce` function and your code may be clear but nothing change the time complexity.

But in this scenario you only need  `map` function:

```js
const obj = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'parent1',
      children: [ 
          {
            childName: 'child11'
          }
      ]
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'parent2',
      children: [ 
          {
            childName: 'child21'
          },
          {
            childName: 'child22'
          }
      ]
    }
]



 const eObj = obj.flatMap(t=>t.children.map(c =>  { return {p_id: t.id,p_name: t.name, childName: c.childName}}))

console.log(eObj);
```